# com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.SchedulerEngine: PORTLET_ID cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, maven-3, liferay-7, mysql-8.0, liferay-ide

The fields PORTLET_ID and MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME are deprecated in the new versions of this library.
What are the two fields functionally equivalent in the new versions?

IDE: LiferayProjectSDKwithDevStudioCommunityEdition-201910152009-windows-installer.exe
Liferay version: liferay-ce-portal-7.3.0-ga1
Windows 10 64-bit build 1909 on VMWare Workstation Pro 15.5.1 on Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit 19.3 Tricia.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image]

https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.1-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/
https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/deprecated-list.html

I have a multitude of errors in the program. How do I know all the deprecated words with what should be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

Those constants where deprecated in Liferay Portal 7.0 as a part of https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-59681 improvements, see also code changes here: https://github.com/brianchandotcom/liferay-portal/pull/31480/files#diff-752cb5829d58912170a4665b288ce6c6

You have more information this change in Liferay breaking changes page, see:

- https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/reference/-/knowledge_base/r/breaking-changes#removed-all-methods-from-schedulerenginehelper-that-explicitly-schedule-jobs-using-schedulerentry-or-specify-messagelistener-class-names

In that page you can read following information:

> Removed All Methods from SchedulerEngineHelper that Explicitly
>   Schedule Jobs Using SchedulerEntry or Specify MessageListener Class
>   Names
>
> ```
> Date: 2015-Oct-29
> JIRA Ticket: LPS-59681
> ```
>
> What changed?
>
> The following methods were removed from SchedulerEngine:
>
> ```
> SchedulerEngineHelper.addJob(Trigger, StorageType, String, String, Message, String, String, int)
> SchedulerEngineHelper.addJob(Trigger, StorageType, String, String, Object, String, String, int)
> SchedulerEngineHelper.schedule(SchedulerEntry, StorageType, String, int)
> ```
>
> Who is affected?
>
> This affects developers that use the above methods to schedule jobs
>   into the SchedulerEngine. How should I update my code?
>
> You should update your code to call one of these methods:
>
> ```
> SchedulerEngineHelper.schedule(Trigger, StorageType, String, String, Message, int)
> SchedulerEngineHelper.schedule(Trigger, StorageType, String, String, Object, int)
> ```
>
> Instead of simply providing the class name of your scheduled job
>   listener, you should follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Instantiate your MessageListener.
>
> Call SchedulerEngineHelper.register(MessageListener, SchedulerEntry) to register your SchedulerEventMessageListener.
> ```
>
> Why was this change made?
>
> The deleted methods provided facilities that aren’t compatible with
>   using declarative services in an OSGi container. The new approach
>   allows for proper injection of dependencies into scheduled event
>   message listeners.

Comment: I have difficulty in finding the solution.